# Пакеты и Python

Tags: python, пакет, package

Недавно начал работать с Python, раньше даже близко не подходил. Встретился с easy_install, virtualenv, pip, buildout, setuptools, distribute, distutils и другими покемонами. Честно говоря, примерное предназначение вышеназванных систем для работы с пакетами Я понимаю, но очень расплывчато. Их так много и все они разные, про100 голова идет кругом.

Прошу более-менее детально и доступно объяснить их суть и по-возможности описать самые яркие различия. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте. еаsy_install и pip -- это установщики python пакетов. Синтаксис такой:

```
$ еаsy_install package

$ pip install package
```

Пакеты можно устанавливать из любого места, даже из локального каталога. Virtalenv -- это утилита для создания изолированного  python-окружения. В каталог устанавливается интерпретатор python со всеми библиотеками. Таким образом, можно в одной системе держать множество разных версий библиотек, интерпретаторов python и они не будут влиять друг на друга. Создаем окружение ().

```
$ virtualenv env
```

Активируем:

```
$ virtualenv . env/bin/activate
(env)user@localhost:~$
```

Деактивируем:

```
$ deactivate
```

> buildout, setuptools, distribute, distutils

-- инструменты для сборки python-пакетов, а также для публикации на PYPI (setuptools, distribute, distutils).

Читайте документацию,там все есть. Если Вы начинающий, то можно спокойно обойтись без этого 'зоопарка',потом постепенно разберетесь, когда появится необходимость.