# Необходимо ли устанавливать virtualenv для публикации проекта написанном на Python (не Django) на Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv

В общем весь вопрос поместился в заглавие)

Comment: на указанном хостинге заявленные требования предъявляются?

Comment: @titov_andrei Да, [вот ссылка](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)

Comment: там как раз для django написано, а хостингу всё равно - окружение для разработки больше нужно

Comment: @titov_andrei напишите ответ подробней. Желательно указать зачем нужен `virtualenv` и нужен ли он в моем случае при использовании Python.

Comment: уточните, что нужно подробней объяснить? `virtualenv` потянет за собой пакеты и модули, которые необходимы для работы вашего проекта и которых может не оказаться на сервере хостинга.

Comment: @titov_andrei Вот почему при разработке приложения на Python мне не нужен `virtualenv` (все и так работает), а для работы моего проекта на хостинге он может понадобится? Мало-обоснованно склоняюсь к мысли, что `virtualenv` мне не понадобится на хостинге. Но я не знаю подводных камней, не понимаю во что это может вытечь в дальнейшем.

Comment: нужные пакеты можно будет подгружать вручную, по мере необходимости и появлении ошибок, если такие будут, а окружение позволит это предусмотреть и загрузить нужное одним разом

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-python/292312#292312